# Extrema point modulus quadratic function, interval

Tags: analysis

$f:\Bbb [-2,4]\to \Bbb R$, f(x)=|x^2 - 1|. Find extrema points+the extremas of the function

Comment: 1 is a maximum point even though it s not a critical point but what do I do with the rest inside the interval?

Comment: Inside the interval check where the derivative of $f(x)$ is either $0$ or not defined..

Comment: otherwise it is an easy function to plot...so it can be checked from graph

Comment: If it is not defined it doesn't always mean that point is not an extrema,right?

Comment: The critical points are 1 and - 1, but the function is not derivable in these points

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly check the boundary points of the interval :

$$f(-2) = |4-1| =3$$

$$f(4)=|16-1| =15$$

Now check where the derivative of the function is zero or not defined.

NOTE: $\bullet$ The fact that the derivative is zero at at point means that the graph's tangent becomes horizontal, so it takes a dip or fall at those points. Hence these points are the ones where extrema is possible.

$\bullet$ The fact that the derivative is undefined means that either its tangent is vertical, or there is a sharp point in the graph instead of a smooth curve. So it can lead to the formation of a sharp hill or valley. However this is not always the case as it might be decreasing through a sharp point. eg.

[image]

Here (y=|x|), the derivative at x=0 is not defined , and thus forms a sharp valley at x=0. hence it is a point of minima.

In general the points of extremum occur when. the sign of the derivative changes, i.e the curve starts to fall from that point if it was rising before that point, or vice versa.

So to answer your question in the comments, no it is not necessary that point of extrema will be there where the derivative is not defined, but it is one of the points where it is possible, so you should check at the point.

Now in the asked question the sharp points occur at $x= \pm 1$.

So  to check at those points,

$$f(\pm1) = 0 $$

Finally the derivative is $0$ at $x=0$, so

$$f(0) = 1$$

So from the determined values, $x= \pm1$ are points of global minima and $x=4$ is global maxima.

Although this problem is easily solved by plotting the graph.

[image]

Here you can see the points of extrema clearly.